# What if Phoenix A collided with UY Scuti

Tags: gravity, black-holes, stars

What if Phoenix A collided with UY Scuti? Phoenix A is estimated to be 100 billion times bigger than the suns radius, while UY Scuti is estimated to be 1700 billion times bigger than the sun. What I want to know is would UY Scuti (a star) have any effect on Phoenix A (a black hole.)

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tidal_disruption_event